# Overriding equals not working

Tags: java, overriding, equals

Here is my problem:
when I try to Override equals method of "my class", it simply doesn't work, the function called is the most abstract one and not the "my class" equals method! Here is some code of my program:
this is the "my class" equals code:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    StudentProxy s = (StudentProxy)o;
    return Matricola == s.Matricola && Name == s.Name && Surname == s.Surname;
}
```

and here is where my Assertion fail:

```
@Test
public void storeStudentTest() throws Exception{
    StudenteProxy s = new StudenteProxy(100, "Gianni", "Rosso", 27.2, 132);
    DB.storeStudent(s);
    StudentProxy ret = (StudentProxy)DB.retrieveStudentData(s.getMatricola());
    DB.deleteStudent(s);
    assertEquals(ret, s); // HERE ! ! ! 
}
```

I've also tried with assertTrue :

```
assertTrue(ret.equals(s));
```

but I get AssertionError; I assume that is caused by the fact that the most abstract equals is being called, and since the two objects aren't the same objects it gives me the message AssertionError.

Any Ideas??? :(

P.S.: They should be equals I've checked this many times in different ways so that's not the problem, I've tested this code many times and found the problem is that equals does not Override ;)

Comment: Have you looked in the contents of the object being returned? Also, the fields seem to be objects, you should compare them with `equals()` and not `==` as well.

Comment: Are you sure your code recompiled after your equals addition?

Comment: I'm assuming that Name and Surname are strings so you need to use .equals instead of == on them as @AndrewLogvinov suggests. In addition have you implemented equals on Matricola?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your equals method and debugging. If it compiles with the `@Override` annotation, there should be no way that your method is getting by-passed. Likely, your method is being called but your logic is flawed, as suggested by others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to tell without more information, but it appears that your `Matricola`, `Name` and `Surname` fields are `Object`s, possibly `String`s.  In which case, you should compare them like this:

```
return Matricola.equals(s.Matricola) && Name.equals(s.Name) && Surname.equals(s.Surname);
```

Otherwise you are comparing references.

Comment: It's funny you want to override an `equals()` method but then use `==`.

Comment: its more stupid than funny  @SotiriosDelimanolis and I perfectly know it! :P

Answer (score 0):

for comparing String you should use equals